# Is it possible to use Windows integrated security with Silverlight RIA services

Tags: silverlight, security, ria

If I port an old client/server to Silverlight RIA services, how can I avoid the extra security work?

Ideally, the client would pass the client's windows credentials to the middle tier; the middle tier would impersonate the client and access the database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as memory serves it is possible to set authentication mode in Web.config,

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
</system.web>
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to do the Authentication it is using Windows by default.  To force it though you need a Authorization tag though such as: <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>  Also, you'll want to create a single Authentication Domain Service, but after that it is cake.  By default SL cannot access the user, but it uses Domain Auth Services to communicate the information back to the plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight will work with the ISS authentication quite well. So long as you can get your old authentication working in IIS you should be able to plug into it.

They have some good documentation on how it works, hopefully this is helpful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707361%28v=VS.91%29.aspx

If you did not previously use an IIS based authentication you can write a custom authentication provider that will plug in.